# How to convert datetime with go?

Tags: datetime, parsing, go

I have a datetime data `2021-01-28T14:07:36+09:00` as string.
I want to convert it to time.Time. Tried

```
datetime := "2021-01-28T14:07:36+09:00"
layout := "2006-01-02 15:04:05"
da, err := time.Parse(layout, datetime)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
fmt.Println(da)
```

Output

```
parsing time "2021-01-28T14:07:36+09:00" as "2006-01-02 15:04:05": cannot parse "T14:07:36+09:00" as " "
0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The datetime format is defined in [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339). You can use pre-defined time layout const in [time](https://godoc.org/time#pkg-constants) package.

```
    datetime := "2021-01-28T14:07:36+09:00"
    da, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, datetime)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(da)
```

Check [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/H7a0CLFDVuM) to test this.